# SVN "Athentication Failed" immediately after connecting using svn://

Tags: linux, debian, svn, repository, svnserve

I am trying to connect to my repository on Debian Linux using the `svn://` protocol.

I immediately receive the following response:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://myhostname/myrepo'
svn: E215004: Authentication failed
```

My svnserve.conf contains the following:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

My passwd file contains the following:

```
username = password
```

The root user has 0777 access to the repository recursively. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I added the SVN protocol to allow both connections via `svn://` and `http://`. This solved my problem.